# React api call. I am able to fetch data but how to populate in the front end

Tags: api, reactjs

https://github.com/sidhemu/menu_food
As I am new in react
In Featured.js file I am doing get request and I am getting data back. The problem I am facing is on to display those data in loop. I tried map() but I am getting error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined(…)". Can anyone please look at the code and please let me know where I am missing something or doing something wrong.
The file is in src>js>Featured.js

```
    export default class Featured extends React.Component {
      constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = { }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        var url = 'http://ec2-54-165-240-14.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/api/foodItem';
     Request.get(url).then((response) => {
       this.setState({
         foodinfo: response.body
       })
     })

  }
  render() {
      console.log(this.state.foodinfo);

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <h1>Featured</h1>
          <Card className="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 eachCard">
            <CardImg top width="100%" src="https://tabletopmenu.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/easyPie/Pasta.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBLST2F5EFKIZGXQ&Expires=2079704677&Signature=eSjrIw32apC0gCGpF92%2FxgnELNA%3D" alt="Card image cap" />
            <CardBlock className="cardBlock">
              <CardTitle>Boom Boom Chicken</CardTitle>
              <CardSubtitle>$8.50</CardSubtitle>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign btnClass"></span>
            </CardBlock>
          </Card>         


        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So the data I am getting the data like this

```
[
  {
    "food_item_id": "a095eca7-3dcf-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
    "food_group_id": "eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
    "food_item_name": "Don't know jack",
    "food_item_pic": "https://tabletopmenu.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/easyPie/dont-know-jack.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBLST2F5EFKIZGXQ&Expires=2080062718&Signature=1OFv2yjaLYBp4lBflKoCOTHl9NQ%3D",
    "food_item_price": 8.5,
    "food_item_price_s": 0,
    "food_item_price_l": 0,
    "food_item_short_desc": "Our signature all beef patty topped with pepper jack cheese, jalapenos, lettuce and mango salsa",
    "food_item_long_desc": "",
    "allergy_profile1": "",
    "allergy_profile2": "",
    "allergy_profile3": "",
    "allergy_profile4": "",
    "drink_pairing1": "",
    "drink_pairing2": "",
    "drink_pairing3": "",
    "drink_pairing4": "",
    "drink_pairing5": "",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  },
  {
    "food_item_id": "a09b073d-3dcf-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
    "food_group_id": "ebaeef2c-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347",
    "food_item_name": "Oreo cookie monster",
    "food_item_pic": "https://tabletopmenu.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/easyPie/oreo_cookie_monster.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJBLST2F5EFKIZGXQ&Expires=2080062718&Signature=4OXMof1S%2BDN1pmdQ%2BSHYyWdevvM%3D",
    "food_item_price": 0,
    "food_item_price_s": 11,
    "food_item_price_l": 15,
    "food_item_short_desc": "Oreo cookie filling, crushed oreo topping, powdered sugar",
    "food_item_long_desc": "",
    "allergy_profile1": "",
    "allergy_profile2": "",
    "allergy_profile3": "",
    "allergy_profile4": "",
    "drink_pairing1": "",
    "drink_pairing2": "",
    "drink_pairing3": "",
    "drink_pairing4": "",
    "drink_pairing5": "",
    "createdAt": null,
    "updatedAt": null
  }
]
```

Now i need to fill  with these data
food_item_name
food_item_pic
food_item_price

Comment: Please, put the code here instead using a link. Besides, that link goes to the root folder of your project, not to the issued file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because React is trying to access the variable before it was instantiate...

You're doin a async call so... it is available **ONLY** after it was received...

Try instantiate  `state` in your constructor with an empty array:

```
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { foodinfo: [] }
  }
```

Comment: One more thing what if I want from those where "food_group_id": "ebaeef2c-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347".

Comment: I can only post after 90 mins

Comment: i have done this api call which gives me this json data but I only want those data where food_group_id eb9fa7e9-3dc9-11e6-a9f9-28e347. 
 you can see the json data in the question

Comment: Enter here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129030/sidhemu-questions

Comment: I dnt have reputations i only have 13